# Capturing UndoManager from SwiftUI environment

Tags: swiftui

I want to be able to access the UndoManager from inside my document model, so I can register undo actions from within the model:

```
// Assume I've extended MyDocument to conform to ReferenceFileDocument elsewhere...
final class MyDocument {
    private var undoManager: UndoManager?

    @Published var aNumber = 5 {
        willSet {
            if let undoManager = undoManager {
                let currentValue = self.aNumber
                undoManager.registerUndo(withTarget: self) { target in
                    target.aNumber = currentValue
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func setUndoManager(undoManager: UndoManager?) {
        self.undoManager = undoManager
    }
}
```

To be register the undoManager, I have tried this:

```
struct DocumentView: View {
    let document : MyDocument
    @Environment(\.undoManager) var undoManager
    
    var body: some View {
        MyDocumentEditor(document: document)
        .onAppear {
            document.setUndoManager(undoManager: undoManager)
        }
    }
}
```

When running my app and loading a saved document this works. But when starting from a new document the UndoManager is nil.

I've tried things like:

```
@Environment(\.undoManager) var undoManager { 
    didSet { 
        self.document.setUndoManager(undoManager: undoManager)
    }
}
```

My objective here is to try and keep as much logic in the model and the views focusing only on UI stuff as much as possible. I wish that ReferenceFileDocument gave a property to access its associated UndoManager as is available with NSDocument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks more natural for SwiftUI to use the following approach

```
var body: some View {
    TopLevelView(document: document, undoManager: undoManager)
}
```

and

```
struct TopLevelView: View {
    @ObservedObject var document : MyDocument
    var undoManager: UndoManager?

    init(document: MyDocument, undoManager: UndoManager?) {
       self.document = document
       self.undoManager = undoManager

       self.setUndoManager(undoManager: undoManager)
    }

    // ... other code
}
```

Comment: Yes - that feels better. However, UndoManager doesn't conform to ObservableObject, so its property definition needs to omit ```@ObservedObject``` and therefore be ```var undoManager: UndoManager?```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this - although it doesn't feel right. At the top level of the View I pass the undoManager to a property I hold on the document:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let document: MyDocument
    @Environment(\.undoManager) var undoManager

    var body: some View {
        document.setUndoManager(undoManager: undoManager)
        return TopLevelView(document: document)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying to figure this out for more than a day, my takeaway is that the `UndoManager` in the `Environment` is the one attached to the `NSWindow` where the view lives. My solution is:

```
protocol Undoable {
   func inverted() -> Self 
}

class Store<State, Action : Undoable> {

   var state : State 
   var reducer : (inout State, Action) -> Void 

   //...init...

   func send(_ action: Action, undoManager: UndoManager) {//passed as an argument
      reducer(&state, action)
      undoManager.registerUndo(withTarget: self){target in 
         target.send(action.inverted())
      }
   }

   //...other methods...

}
```

`Store` can of course be your document class. Now you can pass the `UndoManager` found in the environment from any view that sends actions (pay attentions to sheets and alerts though). Or you automate that step away:

```
class Dispatcher<State, Action : Undoable> : ObservableObject {

   let store : Store<State, Action> 
   let undoManager : UndoManager //see below
   //...init...

   func send(_ action: Action) {
      objectWillChange.send()
      store.send(action, undoManager: undoManager)
   }

}

struct ContentView<State, Action : Undoable> : View {

   @Environment(\.undoManager) var undoManager
   let document : Store<State, Action>

   var body : some View {
      ViewHierarchy().environmentObject(Dispatcher(store: document,
                                                   undoManager: undoManager)
   }

}
```

(maybe you'd need to put the `Dispatcher` into a `StateObject`, I didn't test that part because I'm happy passing the undo manager as a function argument in my small app).

Comment: How would this work if you had a redux like middelware; performing some action that doesn't come from a button/UI event? From what I can telll, \.undoManager is nil unless the former is true (which is very ... annoying)